# Pass a fixture to a helper function in PyTest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a function that needs to utilize a fixture in my test suite. This is just a small helper function that helps to generate a full URL.

```
def gen_url(endpoint):
    return "{}/{}".format(api_url, endpoint)
```

I have a fixture in `conftest.py` that returns the URL:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=["http://www.example.com"])
def api_url(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=["MySecretKey"])
def api_key(request):
    return request.param
```

Finally, in my test function, I need to call my `gen_url`:

```
def test_call_action_url(key_key):
    url = gen_url("player")
    # url should equal: 'http://www.example.com/player'
    # Do rest of test here...
```

When I do this, though, it throws an error saying that `api_url` isn't defined when `gen_url` is called. If I add `api_url` as a second parameter, I need to pass it as a second parameter. That's...not what I want to do.

Can I add `api_url` as a second parameter to `gen_url` without being required to pass it from the tests? Why can't I use it like `api_key` in my `test_*` function?

Comment: Why don't you want to pass `api_url` to `gen_url`?

Answer (score 11):

If you make `gen_url` a fixture, it can request `api_url` without explicitly passing it:

```
@pytest.fixture
def gen_url(api_url):
    def _gen_url(endpoint):
        return '{}/{}'.format(api_url, endpoint)
    return _gen_url


def test_call_action_url(api_key, gen_url):
    url = gen_url('player')
    # ...
```

Additionally, if `api_key` is only used to make requests, a TestClient class
could encapsulate it, so test methods would only require the client:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urljoin  # Python 2

import requests

@pytest.fixture
def client(api_url, api_key):
    class TestClient(requests.Session):
        def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
            url = urljoin(api_url, api_key)
            return super(TestClient, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

    # Presuming API key is passed as Authorization header
    return TestClient(headers={'Authorization': api_key})


def test_call_action_url(client):
    response = client.get('player')  # requests <api_url>/player
    # ...
```

Comment: Is this now deprecated? https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly

Comment: No, because the `gen_url` fixture above is never called directly – it is requested by the test method, and when evaluated, it returns a _new_ method which just so happens to share the name `gen_url`.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. Got confused by the same name.

Comment: I went ahead and renamed the inner method to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -2):

multiple problems with your code, the fixture is not visible in your test code untill and unless you use it as your test parameter, you are not passing both the fixtures (`api_url` and `api_key`) to your test function and subsequently to your helper function. 
Here is the modified code (untested)

```
def gen_url(api_url, endpoint):
   return "{}/{}".format(api_url, endpoint)

def test_call_action_url(api_url, api_key):
   url = gen_url(api_url, "player")
   # url should equal: 'http://www.example.com/player'
   # Do rest of test here with api_key here...
```